# Libreoffice Unity Launcher Doesn't Work

Tags: unity, libreoffice

Has anyone else experienced this situation?

I can only click one single time on **Libreoffice writer 3.4** Unity Launcher.

Then, it simply freeses and don't respond... Any way to fix it?

Comment: Are you able to launch LibreOffice Writer from the command line?  The reason I ask is because sometimes output to the terminal may provide some insight as to what had gone awry.

Comment: Yes, i can get acess from the command line. I can't get really acess from Unity Panel, but only Libreoffice Writer... The others , like the Impress for instance works well.

Comment: This sounds like a bug report to me - if you could please report this as a bug that'd be great. For more on that, look at this question: [How do I report a bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)?

Comment: Do a search on Dash, for 'libre', and pin the editor icon to your launcher.  Then try that icon.

This will identify if the problem is between launcher and the app. or lower down (within LibreOffice setup).

Comment: Have you added any quicklists for libre office? Just curious if there might be a typo in any edited/created libreoffice-writer.desktop file. What happens if you try to launch writer using: libreoffice --writer %U ? Does it also freeze?

Comment: Do you still experience this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug already opened for it in Launchpad, that is to be released soon:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/842566